# Power BI Top N Destination plus Other

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in Power BI (ARM DATA), where I have Destination and CWT (Sales) as columns. I was trying to create a measure with the Top N Destinations (let's say 11) and the rest of Dest in Other. I did this so far:

1. I created a new table Top DEST with the following formula, showing all the destination names +  other

```
Top DEST = 
UNION(
    VALUES('ARM DATA'[Destination]),
    ROW("Destination", "Other")
)
```

2. I created a new measure in the new table Top DEST

```
Top N DEST = 
Var TopNvalue = 11
 
Var TopDEST =
TOPN(
    TopNvalue,
    ALLSELECTED('Top DEST'),
    'ARM DATA'[CWT Total]
    )
    Var AllCWT=
    CALCULATE(
        'ARM DATA'[CWT Total],
        ALLSELECTED('Top DEST')
    )
    Var OtherCWT  = AllCWT - CALCULATE([CWT Total], TopDEST)
 
    Var TopNCWT =
    CALCULATE(
        [CWT Total],
        KEEPFILTERS(
            TopDEST
        )
    )
    Var currentPSubCategory = SELECTEDVALUE('Top DEST'[Destination])
    RETURN
    IF(currentPSubCategory = "Other",
    OtherCWT,
    TopNCWT
    )
```

The result I obtained when I put them in a table are correct but the sum in the table excludes other (it is only Top N). I think this is due to the fact that ARM DATA has no other value and it is only a value in Top DEST. I created a one-to-many relation between Top DEST and ARM DATA. Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Update your question with expression used for Measure `OtherCWT`.

Comment: Other CWT is a variable     Var OtherCWT  = AllCWT - CALCULATE([CWT Total], TopDEST)